# Characters UTF-16LE not showing on my Android Nougat

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, textview

[image][image: Characters correctly show]

I am developing an Android Application and I need to display on a TextView special UTF-16LE characters like æ or Œ, or the one in the picture I posted.

I can't understand why everything is displayed correctly on Nougat Emulator and also on an Lollipop and Marshmallow Smartphone while on my Personal Android Nougat I can't see those characters, I can only see ": :" characters instead of the right ones.

(**Careful**, In the left picture, that ' character is not a normal accent and that I is not a normal I)

Why can't I display those special characters on my Smartphone? How should I proceed with that?

**I debugged my application and characters are properly set on my TextView; but still, I can't read them correctly.**

It seems that my Smartphone (OnePlus3 on latest Software Updates) can't read UTF-16LE characters, but still, It's really strange for me to face something like that.

Any help would be very appreciated,

Have a nice day.

**UPDATE**: I downloaded https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.madore.android.unicodeMap on my Smartphone and it seems that I don't have many of those unicode characters on my Smartphone, is there a way to fix it? Do I just need to install a better font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue, that's what I did. (As usual, thanks also to @Claffolo, my teammate)

I imported a free copyrighted font like Gentium in my android assets.
/assets/fonts/

On my project, I imported the new font and init a variable like that

```
        Typeface plain = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/GentiumPlus-I.ttf");

    final TextView text_view = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    text_view.setTypeface(plain);
   text_view.setText("[String with special characters]");
```

When I loaded my ArrayList with all the special characters, let's say my **wordlist**.

I did it in the following way:

```
//Loading my Wordlist
BufferedReader line_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ipautf16le), Charset.forName("UTF-16LE")));

String line;
try {
    while ((line = line_reader.readLine()) != null) {
        WordList.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Collections.sort(WordList);
```

That's all.